# Dual booting pre installed Windos 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 (SSD + HDD)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I got this new laptop with Windows 7 pre-installed and I wish to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with it. Here is the partition I have currently and I don't know what to make of the `SYSTEM_DRV'. Basically, it is a 256 GB SSD + 500 GB HDD system.

[image: Current Partition]

The plan is to install Ubuntu and Windows on the SSD while keeping all the HDD for storage.

How do I go about doing this (as Windows 7 currently takes the whole of the SSD and I don't know what to do with the Lenovo_recovery and system_drv)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave those partitions alone. You don't need to install Ubuntu on an SSD: it's pretty fast as it is. Instead, resize the Data partition and leave some space for Ubuntu, which you can format from the setup.

If you really want Ubuntu on your SSD, resize your Windows 7 partition from 220GB to 180GB, so that there's 40GB of free space. Boot into the Ubuntu installer, and choose the "Something Else..." option when asked how you want to install Ubuntu.

From here, right click the 40GB partition on the second drive (`sdb`), select (I think) "Properties," format it as `ext4` and mount it as `/`. Then, right click the partition you made on the first drive (`sda`), format it as `ext4` and mount it as `/home`.

Proceed with the installation, and you should have a successful dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows, with the Ubuntu OS itself on the SSD and all your data on the HDD.

If you need any more details or help with this, by all means, comment and I'll help. Sorry for the unspecific instructions; I don't have an install screen in front of me at the moment.

Comment: So, shouldn't /home go in the hdd?
Also, will the hdd parition be the common accessible drive or should I format any drive for it?

Comment: `/home` goes on the new partition you make on the HDD, yes. `/` goes on the new partition on the SSD. Don't format any drive. If you want to access Ubuntu data from Windows, copy the files to the Data partition or install `ext2fsd` on Windows.

Comment: ...and I have an 8  GB ram. So, no swap? I might be using it for some extensive engineering work.

Comment: You can do swap, but you shouldn't have to.

Comment: In "Device for boot loader installation", what should I choose? Which drive?

Comment: I think you want `sdb`. If you can't boot afterward, tell me.

Comment: Got it! Chose the drive where / was installed.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. I'm also hoping that's where Windows put its bootloader files.

Comment: It's a little confusing that Drive 0/sda is your data drive and Drive 1/sdb is  your boot drive, but if it works I won't question it.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot. Bootloader is working perfectly fine.

Comment: That's great! So everything is good so far? You can boot into Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Yup! Although, in grub2, I get two windows options.
One with (sda1) in the end and the other with (sda2).

Everything else is perfect.

Comment: Weird. Do they both work? You can get GRUB Customizer to remove one of them if you want.

Comment: I'm sorry. One of them is (sdb1) and the other is (sdb2), if that matters. Yes, both of them work fine. I'll remove one of them using GRUB customizer. Thanks again!